# pandas minute data column to 60 minute columns

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I've seen related topics using transposition or pivot, but can't make it work.
I've got data frame with two columns, timestamp and minute-like data.

I want to transpose the data frame so that I end up with 61 columns, as follows;

Old DF looks like

```
    Date                    Value   
0   2017-01-01 16:45        12  
1   2017-01-01 16:46        22  
    ...                     ...
n   2017-03-01 11:45        12
```

I want the new DF essentially to be

```
    DayHour           ...   Minute45   Minute46   ...   
0   2017-01-01 16     ...   12         22         ...
    ...               ...   ...        ...        ...
n   2017-03-01 11     ...   12         ...        ...
```

I somehow managed to do this via groupby and for loop over 60 minutes,
but I wonder if there is more compact way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create new columns for DayHour and minute and then pivot the table.

```
df.assign(DayHour = df.Date.dt.floor('h'), minute=df.Date.dt.minute)\
  .pivot(index='DayHour', columns='minute', values='Value')\
  .add_prefix('Minute')

minute               Minute45  Minute46
DayHour                                
2017-01-01 16:00:00      12.0      22.0
2017-03-01 11:00:00      12.0       NaN
```

Comment: .dt.floor... nice.  +1

Comment: Two questions in a row with it :)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks. +1

Comment: I just found that probably due to different versions of pandas or python it is safer to use `pivot_table` istead of `pivot`

Answer (score 1):

Taking `.dt.floor` from @TedPetrou with `set_index` and `unstack`

```
In [58]: (df.set_index([df.Date.dt.floor('h'), df.Date.dt.minute])['Value']
            .unstack().add_prefix('Minute'))
Out[58]:
Date                 Minute45  Minute46
Date
2017-01-01 16:00:00      12.0      22.0
2017-03-01 11:00:00      12.0       NaN
```